# How to recreate the UITableViewController's initializing behavior?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I am creating my own base class that will act as a `UITableViewController` replacement (let's call it `IRTableViewController`). Thus, I am subclassing `UIViewController` and I want to have the following initializers, in a similar fashion to the `UITableViewController`:

```
-(id)init;
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style;
```

The implementation for the above looks like this:

```
-(id)init
{
    return [self initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
}


// The designated initializer of the superclass must call the new designated initializer
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    return [self initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
}


// The designated initializer, must call the superclass designated initializer
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self)
    {
        self.style = style;
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now, if I **do not** override `-loadView`, things work as desired **when I have a nib file** and I initialize a new subclass using one of the following:

```
MyIRTableViewController *vc = [[MyIRTableViewController alloc] init];
MyIRTableViewController *vc = [[MyIRTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
MyIRTableViewController *vc = [[MyIRTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
MyIRTableViewController *vc = [[MyIRTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyIRTableViewController" bundle:nil];
```

The problem comes when I want to use my base class **without** a nib file. In that case, to my understanding, I need to set the view property (as well as add a `UITableView` subview) in `-loadView`. But if I override this method, that means that it will run in all cases, even when initializing objects **with** an associated nib file.

Is there a way to do what I want? And even worse, if I override `-loadView`, according to the docs, I am not supposed to call `[super loadView]`, so how would I ignore whatever happens there when I have a nib file?

PS. I have seen [Matt Gallagher's related post](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/03/recreating-uitableviewcontroller-to.html), but in his case he calls `[super loadView]` and I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an aversion to calling `[super loadView]` in the case where `nibName != nil` you could always load the nib yourself using `loadNibNamed:(NSString *)name owner:(id)owner options:(NSDictionary *)options` ?